# Openshift ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server

Tags: mysql, openshift

MySql is not started , with the error

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'xxxxxxxxxxx-yyyyyy.rhcloud.com' (111)
```

I used ctl_all restart from shell but , still it isn't starting.

```
env | grep OPENSHIFT
```

doesnt show any db script to start. Any idea whats happening.

Comment: can you connect to MYSQL server using ssh? let me know